# Github Actions - Run server & frontend, then execute tests

Tags: jestjs, continuous-integration, cypress, github-actions

I would like to use Github Actions for CI and run tests before the branch can be merged.

I have a single repository that has both my server and frontend within it (Nest & Angular). 
I am using Cypress/Jest for my tests.

I need my backend server running for my frontend cypress tests to pass.
Currently GH Actions doesn't move onto the next step because the backend process is running - but that's what I need to happen...

How should I set this up so that I can use GH Actions for CI?

```yaml
name: test
on: [push]
env:
  CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  OTHER_SECRETS: ${{ secrets.otherSecrets }}
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: macos-11
    steps:
      # start cypress w/github action: https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action
      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.5.0
        with:
          node-version: '16.13.0'
      - name: Checkout
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v2'
      - name: "Start Backend"
        run: |
          cd server &&
          npm install &&
          npm run build &&
          npm run start:prod
      - name: "Start Frontend"
        run: |
          npm install &&
          npm run build &&
          npm run start
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          record: true
          browser: chrome
      - name: "Run Jest Tests"
        run: |
            cd server &&
            npm run test
```

#note: I have tried appending the "&& sleep 10 && curl http://localhost:port -i" option to the npm commands - and it hasn't worked for me.

#note2: It's my first time w/ GH Actions, so maybe I'm missing something obvious!!

Comment: Have you seen service containers? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers

Comment: I had not but read the documentation via the link you shared - thank you.

It seems like a heavy handed solution to this problem, although it may work and perhaps it is the only solution..

It seems using this approach I'd have to containerize my backend server and then host the image on Docker Hub - I really just want to verify the server is up and running - then move on to the next step or job.

Comment: You could also use docker-compose to spin up multiple containers (but you'd have containerise your backend server as well)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62507091

Answer (score 3):

> #note: I have tried appending the "&& sleep 10 && curl http://localhost:port -i" option to the npm commands - and it hasn't worked for me.

There is a slight error here, `&&` will wait for the previous command to complete and only run the next one if it is successful `&` would run the previous command in the background and then will move on to running the next one. Therefore as nothing stops your server, `&&` won't work.

I am not sure it is the cleanest way but the following should work, I have used an equivalent to run a UI in one of my projects.

```
  - name: "Start Backend"
    run: |
      cd server &&
      npm install &&
      npm run build &&
      npm run start:prod &
      sleep 5 &&
      curl http://localhost:port -I
  - name: "Start Frontend"
    run: |
      npm install &&
      npm run build &&
      npm run start &
      sleep 5 &&
      curl http://localhost:port -I
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, server running but never moving to the next step of running the Cypress tests.
Thanks didwefixit, using just one & worked to start the server and then run Cypress test script worked:

```
 jobs: 
  build: 
    env:
      CI: true
    strategy: 
      matrix: 
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x]
    runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    steps: 
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js version ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with: 
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm install --prefix client
      - run: npm install --prefix server
      - run: npm install 
      - run: npm run build --prefix client
      - run: npm run start --prefix server & npm run test
```

script in client package.json:

```
"build": "BUILD_PATH=../server/public react-scripts build"
```

script in server package.json:

```
"start": "node src/server.js"
```

script in root package.json:

```
"test": "npx cypress run"
```