# How to run server and tests within Github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have this github action:

```
jobs:
  run-server:
    name: Run Contract Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - ...
      - name: Start Server
        run: iex -S mix phx.server

  run-tests:
    name: Run Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: run-server
    ...
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run API Tests
        id: run-newman
        uses: anthonyvscode/newman-action@v1
        ...
```

But the server closes before the second job starts. How do I keep the server going while I run the contract tests?

Comment: Why is the server not started in the same job as the tests? IIRC, by default, the jobs run in parallel and a job runs in its own runner. These docs might be helpful: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#jobs and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62507091